# Assertions in a finished script?

Tags: python, function, assertion

I just finished a convolution script for images.

Now, my function looks like:

```py
def conv(image: np.ndarray,
         conv: np.ndarray, *args):

    assert 1 < image.ndim < 4, "error0"
    assert conv.ndim is 2, "error1"
    xconv, yconv = conv.shape
    assert xconv == yconv and xconv % 2, "error2"
    # computations
```

If any of those assertions is not satisfied, then the input is wrong and most probably the function will give an error.

Although, the user will not be able to understand what's wrong, plus the delay until it reaches the error.

Everywhere I read that `assert` is used for debugging. Is it better to "slow down" my algorithm everytime it runs rather than slower and undocumented errors (he has to refer to docstring)? What's the most common practice in those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What's the most common practice in those cases?*

You could `raise Exception` with short description of why it happend, so in your case for example you can do:

```
if not 1 < image.ndim < 4:
    raise Exception("Incorrect number of dimensions")
```

instead of

```
assert 1 < image.ndim < 4, "error0"
```

Note the `not` (negation of condiction). For more data see [docs fo Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Is this practice a convention or does it help with performance? (I have read numerous times that "not" statement slows down the process)

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic you can decide to rewrite your conditions in `not`-less style, for example `if image.ndim <=1 or image.ndim >=4:` but I would not except big difference there. I suggest taking at look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module, which allow testing speed of code execution.